# How to do search with first letter in individual column searching datatable

Tags: javascript, search, datatables

I'am working on a web app with datatable.
I've done global research bar and individual research bar, like this example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
Now what I want to do is to start research by the first letter only in the individuals columns.
I tried to do this whith global research and it worked fine, thank to this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table=$('#example').DataTable( {
       responsive: true
   } );
    $('.dataTables_filter input').on( 'keyup', function (e) {
      var regExSearch = '\\b' + this.value;
    table.search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
   });
} );
```

But this is not what I want
And I have programmed my individual research like that :

```
table.columns(':gt(1)').every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search(this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

I tried to use the same logic as global research while adding
`.search('\\b' +this.value )`
but when I try to search something, nothing is returned.

Maybe I do something wrong, does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was so close.
The only thing I had to do is :

```
table.columns(':gt(1)').every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search('\^'+this.value, true, false ) // regex=true, smart=false
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

And it work.